# how to create nginx file for mlab database collection search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, mongoose, mlab

i want to do a task which first extract the details from url like,if i have url like,

http://example.com/country/city/name

then use [country,city,name] to find in mlab database collection, like "landmarks" collection,

and select "_id" of this combination stored in "landmarks" collection, then forward this to ,

http://api.example.com/landmarks/_id

with request, response header and logged in user in request header and get response from there on site example.com

how to create db search file in nginx before forwarding to next url ?

Comment: What have you come up with till now?

Comment: @TarunLalwani nothing yet on this task, i dont know how to create this kind of file, what i was known about nginx that it will receive one url and forword to another, and directory path can be set and on that directory if 10 files are there then on changing name in url new page can be shown ...but my task is different....and previously we were doing it using _id in the url of api and showing id in url also, and we were doing search by id and reflect back results...now we want to modify as explained